# how to display alert box in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a registration page with a submit button.

i want to show an alert box when the "user clicks on the submit button" after which the "data entered by the user is inserted in the database."

```
int i = obj.IU_SubscriberMaster(0, txtFirstname.Text, txtLastname.Text, txtEmail.Text, txtPassword.Text);

        if (i > 0)
        {
            Call ErrorTrap("errormsg");
        }
```

this is where i want to show the alert.
i used

```
    function alerts(str) {
    return false;
}
```

and than by creating a function errortrap

```
public void ErrorTrap(string str)
{
    if (!ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("alert"))
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alerts('" + str + "');", true);
    }
}
```

but it did not work

can anyone please help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Regular Page

```
public void ErrorTrap(string str)
{
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert" + UniqueID, 
     "alert('" + str + "');", true);
}
```

### Ajax Page

You need to use ScriptManager if you use ajax.

```
public void ErrorTrap(string str)
{
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "alert" + UniqueID, 
      "alert('" + str + "');", true);
}
```

Comment: when I run the "Regular Page" one I notice that the alert happens before some of my positioning css on the menu items

Answer (score 1):

`alerts`:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alerts('" + str + "');", true);
```

needs to be `alert`:

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + str + "');", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean for the javascript to be `"alerts("+ str + "');"` and not `"alert(" + str + "');"`?

Answer (score 0):

`alerts` should be `alert`. if you are using ajax, better use ScriptManager.