# Did I pass it correct from C# variables to assign it in Javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I need to pass 2 public variables from C# `output` and `deviceName` to Javascript(#txt) after click execute button.

When I run it, I didn't get any error but I didn't get javascript return result either success or failed that was suppose to be display on html div id `#output`. I want it to pass to Javascript when I click `ExcuteCode` button

Here is C# code behind,

```
   public Collection<PSObject> output = new Collection<PSObject>();
        public string deviceName = "";
      public string ipAddresses = "";
      public string YourScript = "";

    protected void ExecuteCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         foreach(PSObject psObject in output)
            {
                ipAddress = "" + psObject;

                foreach(var id in tbids)
                    try
                    {
                        name = Request[id];
                        deviceName += Request[id] + "\r\n";  

                        Pipeline pipeline2 = runSpace2.CreatePipeline();
                        Command invokeScript2 = new Command("Invoke-Command");

                        //Add powershell script file and arguments into scriptblock
                        ScriptBlock sb2 = invoke.Invoke(@"{D:\Scripts\Set-IPAddress.ps1 " + ipAddress + " " + name + "}")[0].BaseObject as ScriptBlock;

                        invokeScript2.Parameters.Add("scriptBlock", sb2);

                        invokeScript2.Parameters.Add("computername", TextBoxServer.Text);

                        pipeline2.Commands.Add(invokeScript2);


                        tbids.RemoveAt(0);

                        Collection<PSObject> output2 = pipeline2.Invoke();

                        foreach(PSObject psObject2 in output2)
                        {
                            str = str + psObject2;
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }
YourScript = "CreateIsm();";

            }


        }
```

Here is a javascript codes in aspx,

```
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>

            // global variables
            id = '<%= Rim.NEAt.GetUserID().ToString() %>';
            notes = '';
            ismClassId = '';
            caseType = '';
            l1 = '';
            l2 = '';
            l3 = '';

    $(document).ready(function(){

            <%=YourScript%>

            // Create ISM Ticket
            CreateIsm = function (funct) {

alert('<%=ipAddresses%>');
        alert('<%=deviceName%>');

                var txt = $("#txt");
                txt.val("Please add the following DNS entries\n" + document.getElementById("<%=output%>") + "\n" + document.getElementById("<%=deviceName%>"));

                notes = $('#txt').val();
                ismClassId = 'RIM31038';
                caseType = 'Request';
                l1 = 'Request';
                l2 = 'Network';
                l3 = 'Static IP Address';

                notes = $('#txt').val();

                $.support.cors = true;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://********.com/Common/Components/ISM/SubmissionPage.aspx",
                    data: {
                        'Form_ID': '08.01.7',
                        'ISM_Class_ID': ismClassId,
                        'Case_Type': caseType,
                        'Level_1': l1,
                        'Level_2': l2,
                        'Level_3': l3,
                        'Case_Notes': notes,
                        'Contact_ID': id
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        //console.log(data);
                        var str = data;
                        var ticket = $(str).find("#ticketIDOutput").val();
                        var hreff = "http://********.com/Form/SRApproval/SRApproval.aspx?ticketID=" + ticket;
                        var a = "<a href='" + hreff + "' target='blank'>" + ticket + "</a> created."
                        $('#output').html(a);

                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                        $('#output').html("Error creating ISM ticket: " + textStatus + " - " + errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            }; 
    };

        </script>  

        </head>
```

Comment: Output in the code behind is a collection, yet you are using it as an ID (GetElementById) does not seem right?

Comment: Seems like it, I was using that example from other website. If it wrongs, what is the correct way?

Comment: it depends what you want to do, it seems to me that you are expecting to parse a collection created server side, in that case you would need to loop client side to generate a client cllection or create a server side method to parse the collection as a suitable string

Answer (score 0):

If you want ASPX page to access code behind's property or method, it needs to be `Public`.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" 
   CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" 
   Inherits="WebApplication.Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('<%= MyValue %>');
        alert('<%= MyMethod() %>');
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    </form>
</body>
</html>

public string MyValue;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        MyValue = "one";
    }
}

public string MyMethod()
{
    return "two";
}
```

Comment: What is the type and name of the variable you are accessing?

Comment: C# public string variables are `output` and `deviceName`.

Comment: `output` is `Collection<PSObject>`. Javascript cannot parse it. The property must be of type string (or other [value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch(v=vs.90).aspx)) *By the way, how are planing to retrieve that `output` value from javascript?*

Comment: I modify my codes above by adding another public string variable `ipAddresses` to get values from `output` Collection. I also add at the bottom of executeCode click function where it assign a javascript function to call.

Comment: I tested it and it show no response because I added  `alert('<%=ipAddresses%>');` in `CreateIsm = function (funct)`. It was suppose to show a popup screen to show proof that it acutally call and run this javascript function.

Comment: Does it work if you just simple display at `$(document).ready(function(){ alert('<%=ipAddresses%>'); });`. Can you able to see `ipaddresses` in client side View Source?

Comment: It does work to call this function but the alert result is empty because it already executed on page load before I do anything. Should I use `<%=YourScript%>` inside document ready function to call CreateIsm function?

Comment: Look like you assign the value to `ipAddresses` very early in the page life cycle. *I cannot answer your question as I do not see the rest of your code.*

Comment: It started as empty string and it doesn't assign it until I click the button which it call `ExecuteCode_Click` C# function as it already post example above. I added `YourScript = "CreateIsm();"; ` at the bottom of `ExecuteCode_Click` function so that it can call javascript `<%=YourScript%>` inside document.ready function. However it seems it doesn't response this call.

Comment: In your scenario, you want to use [RegisterStartupScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818501/how-to-display-alert-box-in-asp-net/15819723#15819723) instead of `<%=YourScript%>`