# RegisterStartupScript on page launch - How can this be done?

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind, scriptmanager, registerstartupscript

I apologize for what may seem like a rudimentary question, but there's still so much to learn in C#!

I am trying to have a pop-up message when a page loads, under certain conditions.

I have my If/Else If all set up and it works fine, and now I need to add a pop-up message when certain conditions are met.

My problem is, I have only ever used something like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(btnSubmitWork, typeof(Button), "Data Entry", 
"alert('Please note that you are in the UAT link')", true);
```

However, this time there will be no button involved, I want it to just pop up when the page loads.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to display alert box in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818501/how-to-display-alert-box-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using a button use `Page` and `GetType()` as the first two params:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "Data Entry", 
"alert('Please note that you are in the UAT link');", true);
```

Comment: Can you make the 2 edits I noted in my answer below so your answer is complete and correct?  Thanks!

Comment: @JohnnyBones Nice one, all sorted now. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

With a combination of hutchonoid's answer and the accepted answer posted at the link, I was able to get it to work using this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "Data Entry", 
"alert('Please note that you are in the UAT link');", true);
```

Just 2 tiny differences; using "Page.GetType()" instead of just "GetType()", and a semicolon at the end of the Alert message.  I'll give hutchonoid the check since he got me most of the way there.